# realpath error with Chez Scheme when Installing Idris2

Tags: macos, idris, chez-scheme

This is my machine

```
Software:

System Software Overview:

  System Version: macOS 10.14.6 (18G103)
  Kernel Version: Darwin 18.7.0
```

I'm following [this guide](https://idris2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/starting.html) to install Idris2.

What I've done thus far is

1. `brew install idris` validated with `idris` command
2. `brew install chezscheme` validated with `petite` command
3. `brew install gmp` not validated
4. `git clone https://github.com/edwinb/Idris2.git`
5. `make install` in the repo

It took sometime to type check then it began to do something with Chez Scheme until it hit an error. Heres the last few lines of output before the error

```
Found Chez Scheme at /usr/local/bin/chez
chez/chez001: success
chez/chez002: success
chez/chez003: success
chez/chez004: success
chez/chez005: success
chez/chez006: success
chez/chez007: success
chez/chez008: success
chez/chez009: success
chez/chez010: success
chez/chez011: success
chez/chez012: success
chez/chez013: success
chez/chez014: success
chez/chez015: success
./run: line 2: realpath: command not found
./run: line 6: : command not found
chez/chez016: FAILURE
Golden value differs from actual value.
Accept actual value as new golden value? [yn]
y
chez/reg001: success
218/219 tests successful
make[1]: *** [test] Error 1
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

now when i run `idris2` command im getting the following:

```
$ idris2
zsh: permission denied: idris2
$ sudo idris2
Password:
sudo: idris2: command not found
```

## UPDATE ON RESOLUTION

make sure to add `~/.idris2/bin` to your `$PATH` environment variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
brew install coreutils
```

this issue and its solution is described on git. You can look at it at [this link](https://github.com/react-native-community/jsc-android-buildscripts/issues/20).

Comment: thanks! Its able to compile i think. I'm able to see a file `~/.idris2/bin/idris2` however i can't seem to run it as a command, any ideas why? running `$ idris2` still gives permission denied and command not found.

Comment: can you post your `make test` logs, there could be something missing.

Comment: [heres the logs](http://snippi.com/s/4k2355a) previously `chez016` was failing and i just entered `y` for the golden value prompt. Then the `make install` after works.

Comment: have a look at my next answer hope that will help you run Idris2

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding idris2 to the PATH didn't work out.
However, I found a partial solution here: https://gitmemory.com/andorp

> Adding IDRIS_CG=racket not IDRIS2_CG=racket did not help. Still got
> the same
>
> idris2 --build idris2.ipkg make: idris2: Command not found error.
>
> If I crudely change the Makefile by hand:
>
> -export IDRIS2_BOOT ?= idris2
> +export IDRIS2_BOOT ?= ~/.idris2/bin/idris2
> +export IDRIS2_CG = racket The make all and friends starts to working

Unfortunately, I got stuck again a little later on... However, it did allow me to execute the "make install-api" command.

Comment: If you are building without an existing `idris2` executable, you should execute `make bootstrap-racket && make install` WITHOUT executing `make all`.

Answer (score -1):

i can run idris2 from `.idris2/bin`
if you cannot run it even trying `./idris2` try `chmod +x idris2` and run again.
[image]

Comment: I deleted .idris2 and the repo, cloned a new one make install again, still failed. added idris2 to my path, and then it worked. not sure why, but hey its working. Thanks for looking into my issue.

Comment: are you sure this should be a separate answer rather than an addition to your first answer? on its own, it won't answer the question: you need both, no?